# Amazon submit feed Success,but the price does not update,what's wrong?Tested the XML with the Scratchpad,it works

Tags: php, price, amazon-mws, wms

**Code:**
This code can submit with success,
and it can get the right response using the Scratchpad tool.
But it doesn't work at last!
How can I modify?

I also had tested the XML using the Scratchpad tool，it works.

```
$file = 'test.xml';
$i = 1;
$sku = "xxxxx";
$new_price = 20.59;
$merchant_ID = Config("MERCHANT_ID");
$currency = "USD";

$feed = <<< EOD
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
    <Header>
       <DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion> 
       <MerchantIdentifier>$merchant_ID</MerchantIdentifier>
   </Header>
   <MessageType>Price</MessageType>
   <Message>
        <MessageID>$i</MessageID>
        <Price>
            <SKU>$sku</SKU>
            <StandardPrice currency="$currency">$new_price</StandardPrice>
        </Price>
    </Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
EOD;

$feedHandle = @fopen($file, 'w+');
fwrite($feedHandle, $feed);
rewind($feedHandle);

print_r(stream_get_contents($feedHandle));

$params = array(
    'AWSAccessKeyId' => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    'Action' => "SubmitFeed",
    'Merchant' => MERCHANT_ID,
    'MWSAuthToken' => MWSAuthToken,
    'SignatureVersion' => "2",
    'Timestamp'=> gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time()),
    'Version'=> "2009-01-01",
    'SignatureMethod' => "HmacSHA256",
    'FeedType' => '_POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_',
    'MarketplaceIdList.Id.1' => MARKETPLACE_ID,
    'PurgeAndReplace' => 'false',
    'ContentMD5Value'=> base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($feedHandle), true)),
);

$url_parts = array();
foreach(array_keys($params) as $key)
    $url_parts[] = $key . "=" . str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($params[$key]));

sort($url_parts);

$url_string = implode("&", $url_parts);
$string_to_sign = "POST\nmws.amazonservices.com\n/\n" . $url_string;

// Sign the request
$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, TRUE);

$signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

$url = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/" . '?' . $url_string . "&Signature=" . $signature;
echo $url;

$md5 = base64_encode(md5(stream_get_contents($feedHandle), true));

$httpHeader=array();
$httpHeader[]='Transfer-Encoding: chunked';
$httpHeader[]='Content-type: text/xml';
$httpHeader[]='Content-MD5: ' . $md5;
$httpHeader[]='Expect:';
$httpHeader[]='Accept:';

$ch = curl_init($url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, '<MWS_SubmitFeed>/<1.02> (Language=PHP/' . phpversion() . ')');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UPLOAD,true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$feedHandle); 
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $httpHeader);


$response = curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($response);.
```

**After submission, I get the response like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SubmitFeedResponse xmlns="http://mws.amazonaws.com/doc/2009-01-01/">
<SubmitFeedResult>
    <FeedSubmissionInfo>
        <FeedSubmissionId>50624017558</FeedSubmissionId>
        <FeedType>_POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA_</FeedType>
        <SubmittedDate>2018-01-27T14:03:39+00:00</SubmittedDate>
        <FeedProcessingStatus>_SUBMITTED_</FeedProcessingStatus>
    </FeedSubmissionInfo>
</SubmitFeedResult>
    <ResponseMetadata>
    <RequestId>ad455b8b-7959-451d-b914-fbe2d9cc5ac8</RequestId>
    </ResponseMetadata>
</SubmitFeedResponse>
```

***But when I check the Price of the product, it doesn't change.***

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In amazon StandardPrice accept in text formatt.

Try this

```
$new_price = '20.59' 
<StandardPrice currency="$currency">$new_price</StandardPrice>
```

Comment: thank you, i have tried that ,but it is still the problem.

Comment: hi did you find a solution for this?